# Regex in square brackets not preceeded or followed by

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a Regex pattern in C# to find in a string, any [anything] that is not preceeded or followed by a "."... here is the pattern i have so far, which brings me to the actual problem: it only works on text that is NOT on the very first line??

Pattern:

```
([^\.]\[[^\[]*][^\.])
```

Consider the following "text" value:

```
[F] (never matches even if it should)

[F].[1234] (not a match, correct)

[P] (is a match)
```

If someone could help me with this, i would really appreciate it because i cannot, for the life of me, figure out why the very first line is not considered.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you want to use negative lookbehind, because you don't want to include the character preceding the `[`, do you? Because you are currently including that character also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex as you wrote it validates that the first `[` must have a character that is not `.` in front of it. The first `[` is not preceded by any character so it fails.

With negative assertions you can say "match if there is no `.`".

```
((?<!\.)\[[^\[]*](?!\.))


NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^\[]*                   any character except: '\[' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ]                        ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

Comment: if i wanted to lazy/least '\[', how would i write that? trying to be efficient like: hey, if you find a single [ in there, just stop/the match does not qualify.

Comment: `[^\[]*` stops at the first character that is not a `[` because of the character class so it's fine because there is no backtracking done by the regex engine. `.*\[` would be bad because it would backtrack (in the best case) or match too much (in the worst case). You could modify the `*` to be non-greedy with `.*?\[` to obtain another expression that matches as little as possible. Now is there a real performance difference between `[^\[]*` and `.*?\[`? Probably not, but benchmarking is the only way to obtain a solid answer! If you do benchmark I'd like to know the results. :)

Comment: did the benchmark... not a noticeable difference... my string was pretty large and it was like 2 ms. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this pattern:

```
((^|[^\.])\[[^\[]*][^\.])
```

difference against yours is that `[` could be just the first symbol in the line.

also i suggest you to use a site like http://regex101.com/ to better understand how regex works.